# Can strings be passed between contracts

Tags: string

I want to call a function from another contract. Can I pass a string?

`IUpgrade(upgradeAddress).wrap(label, wrappedOwner, _fuses, resolver);`

label is a string. I read somewhere that you can't pass strings between contracts, but maybe that was only for an older version of solidity.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it out on remix.ethereum and made a demo code below , and yes you can send string between contracts since contract functions are still functions :D

- However the contract function parameter must have a string parameter to take in a string

```
    function foo(string memory content) public pure returns(string memory) {
            return content;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip to just jump into Remix and try it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I used to test it in Remix.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;


interface IName {

    function upgrade (string calldata name) external;

}

contract Storage {

    address public upgradeAddress;


    function setUpgradeAddress(address _upgradeAddress)
        public
    {
            upgradeAddress = _upgradeAddress;
    }

 
    function upgrade(string calldata name) public {
        IName(upgradeAddress).upgrade(name);
    }


}

contract UpgradeStorage is IName{

    string public name;
    
    function upgrade(string calldata _name) public override{
        name = _name;
    }

}
```